# Can't pullout info from Regedit via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I can't get this code to work:

> Get-ChildItem hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall | ForEach-    Object {Get-ItemProperty $*.pspath} | 
>   Where-Object { $*.DisplayName -Eq 'Microsoft Lync 2013'} | Select-Object DisplayVersion

What am i doing wrong?

This one works fine, both of them are in regedit, I am aware that this example is not en wow6432node, could that be the problem?

> Get-ChildItem hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $*.pspath} | 
>   Where-Object { $*.DisplayName -Eq 'Microsoft Security Client'} | Select-Object DisplayVersion

Answer (score -1):

You had several syntax errors. In such cases, I try to resolve the one-liner into multiple steps and write a `.ps1` file to spot the error(s). Copy this into a file of your choice:

```
$a = Get-ChildItem hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall 
$b = $a | ForEach-Object {  Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath} 
$c = $b | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -Eq 'Microsoft Lync 2013'} 
$d = $c | Select-Object DisplayVersion

write-host `$d.length  $d.length
write-host content of `$d 
$d

write-host 
write-host intermediate results were:
write-host `$c.length  $c.length
write-host `$b.length  $b.length
write-host `$a.length  $a.length  

pause
```

I get no results left after step $c in my case, because I do not have Microsoft Lync 2013 installed:

```
PS> .\test.ps1
$d.length 0
content of $d

intermediate results were:
$c.length 0
$b.length 976
$a.length 992
Drücken Sie die Eingabetaste, um den Vorgang fortzusetzen...:
```